# HTML character reference display problems

Tags: php, html, character-encoding, character-reference

I'm currently developing a site in Joomla, and one of the components I'm using makes use of a PHP file to administer the language. (english.php, spanish.php)

The problem I'm having is that if I use the plain text version of eg. "`á`", it will show up in the browser tab title ok, but as a `�` in the body of the page. But if I use a character reference (`&#225;`), the reverse happens!

Any ideas?

Thanks

bren

Comment: So a title like `<title>&#225;</title>` will be displayed as `�`?

Comment: <title>Ve&amp;#237;culos</title> is displaying as "Ve&#237;culos"

edit.. just by typing that i see the problem.. its parsing the '&#237;' as '&amp;#237;' and therefore not seeing the whole code..

but i still am not sure how to fix this..

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

- Use `htmlentities` function for your text

  `$my_text = htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`

**[More info about the htmlentities function.](http://de.php.net/htmlentities)**

- Use proper document type, this did the trick for me.

  `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`
- Use **utf-8** encoding type in your page:

  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: i've got the doctype set as html5 and the charset and utf-8. from what i can see it seems that its not parsing the &#123; as seen but as &amp;#123; ..